# Using HTML5 JS Frameworks for Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm wanting to use HTML5 local storage and have been looking at a lot of the different JS Frameworks like Backbone, Batman, Underscore.  There's a boatload of new JS frameworks and I'm not sure which one to use.

I need to do a lot of Local storage work, (CRUD) so I would prefer a JS Framework that handles the active record stuff for me, relationships, etc.

Additionally, the app I'm wanting to build will have a lot of forms, and is heavily reliant upon input captured from HTML5 forms and JSON objects.

Thus, is there a good framework to use with this in mind?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on what you wish to built. I've been happy with ember.js and this lib for localStorage: https://github.com/emberjs/data
But I'm sure you can find similar libs/plug-ins to backbone, spine, batmen and others.

Btw, if you wish to work with local storage (and later with something that works async like indexedDB) you might want to check http://brian.io/lawnchair/ which is very flexiable library to work with client storage options.

Comment: I've not heard of Lawnchair or EmberJS, but I will take a look.  I am trying to build a game which requires a lot of data (SQLite) and database interactions, a management game would be the best analogy

Comment: If you are working on a game I would read this great post: http://smus.com/game-asset-loader/ that contain lots of good tips and tools you might want to use.